# ASP.net delete row using gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, wizard, delete-row

I'm trying to delete a row using the delete function provided trouhg to gridview wizard.

But when i click on delete I get following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code
```

This is my code:

```
 public void deleteProject(DAL.Project p)
    {
        DAL.Project result = (from project in dc.Projects
                              where project.pk_project_id == p.pk_project_id
                              select project).Single();
        dc.Projects.DeleteOnSubmit(result);
        dc.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

when I debug it the value "p" has no properties.

The strange thing is that when I want to update my rows I use somewhat the same method:

```
 DAL.Project result = (from project in dc.Projects
                              where project.pk_project_id == p.pk_project_id
                              select project).Single();
        result.titel = p.titel;
        result.beschrijving = p.beschrijving;

        dc.SubmitChanges();
```

This goes well. So why doesn't it work with deleting rows?

Comment: it looks like DAL.Project is not being assigned before calling deleteProject, what is different about the update method?

Comment: nvm I thought you meant p was null

Comment: Indeed when I call the delete method "p" = null, but when calling update it is not null. The strange this is i call them both in the same way so their shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You will need to figure out what is different between the two methods and the code that executes these methods.

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerable.Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx) throws an `InvalidOperationException` if the sequnce contains more than one item or theinput sequence is empty. You can use `First` or `FirstOrDefault`:

```
DAL.Project result = (from project in dc.Projects
                      where project.pk_project_id == p.pk_project_id
                      select project).FirstOrDefault();
if(result != null)
{
     // ...
}
```

(However, i don't know why the update work )